# How to add default value in input text field using js

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I bought a plugin ,the plugin is fine but I want to modify a feature ,but the support team seem too busy to help. What I'm going to do is add default value "+886" in the start of the text field.I tried add `defaultValue: "+886"`in the code, but unfortunately not work. This problem has bothered me for 20 days , Can anyone give some hints?

```
wp.element.createElement("label", null, window.vibephoneauth.translations.enter_mobile_no_with_code), wp.element.createElement("input", {
            className: "input",
            type: "tel",
            value: _,
            onChange: function(e) {
                E(e.target.value)
            }
        })
```

original code

```
!function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var a=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(a.exports,a,a.exports,n),a.l=!0,a.exports}n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(n.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var a in e)n.d(r,a,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,a));return r},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=1)}([function(e,t,n){},function(e,t,n){"use strict";n.r(t);n(0);function r(e,t){var n=Object.keys(e);if(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols){var r=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(e);t&&(r=r.filter((function(t){return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(e,t).enumerable}))),n.push.apply(n,r)}return n}function a(e){for(var t=1;t<arguments.length;t++){var n=null!=arguments[t]?arguments[t]:{};t%2?r(Object(n),!0).forEach((function(t){o(e,t,n[t])})):Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors?Object.defineProperties(e,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(n)):r(Object(n)).forEach((function(t){Object.defineProperty(e,t,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(n,t))}))}return e}function o(e,t,n){return t in e?Object.defineProperty(e,t,{value:n,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):e[t]=n,e}function i(e,t){return function(e){if(Array.isArray(e))return e}(e)||function(e,t){if("undefined"==typeof Symbol||!(Symbol.iterator in Object(e)))return;var n=[],r=!0,a=!1,o=void 0;try{for(var i,l=e[Symbol.iterator]();!(r=(i=l.next()).done)&&(n.push(i.value),!t||n.length!==t);r=!0);}catch(e){a=!0,o=e}finally{try{r||null==l.return||l.return()}finally{if(a)throw o}}return n}(e,t)||function(e,t){if(!e)return;if("string"==typeof e)return l(e,t);var n=Object.prototype.toString.call(e).slice(8,-1);"Object"===n&&e.constructor&&(n=e.constructor.name);if("Map"===n||"Set"===n)return Array.from(e);if("Arguments"===n||/^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(n))return l(e,t)}(e,t)||function(){throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.")}()}function l(e,t){(null==t||t>e.length)&&(t=e.length);for(var n=0,r=new Array(t);n<t;n++)r[n]=e[n];return r}var c=wp.element,u=c.useState,s=c.useEffect,p=c.Fragment,m=wp.data.select,d=function(e){var t=i(u(),2),n=t[0],r=t[1],o=i(u(""),2),l=(o[0],o[1],i(u(""),2)),c=l[0],d=l[1],f=i(u(""),2),b=f[0],h=f[1],w=i(u(),2),v=w[0],y=w[1],g=i(u(""),2),_=g[0],E=g[1],O=i(u(),2),N=O[0],j=O[1],S=i(u(!1),2),P=S[0],k=S[1],T=i(u(""),2),C=T[0],I=T[1],x=i(u(""),2),M=x[0],L=x[1],A=i(u(!1),2),q=A[0],D=A[1],J=i(u(!1),2),U=J[0],$=J[1],F=i(u(!1),2),R=F[0],H=F[1],V=function(e){L(e),setTimeout((function(){L("")}),5e3)};s((function(){y(!0)}),[]);var W=function(e){return new Promise((function(t,n){fetch("".concat(window.vibephoneauth.api.url,"/phone_auth_login?client_id=").concat(window.vibebp.settings.client_id),{method:"post",body:JSON.stringify({social:e.credential.signInMethod,client_id:window.vibebp.settings.client_id,user:{email:e.user.email,password:e.user.password,uid:e.user.uid,name:e.user.displayName,avatar:e.user.photoURL,phoneNumber:e.user.phoneNumber,last_login:e.user.metadata.lastSignInTime,create_time:e.user.metadata.creationTime},idToken:e.idToken})}).then((function(e){return e.json()})).then((function(e){t(e)}))}))},z=function(e){fetch("".concat(window.vibebp.api.validate_token,"?client_id=").concat(window.vibebp.settings.client_id),{method:"post",body:e.token}).then((function(e){return e.json()})).then((function(t){if(t.hasOwnProperty("data")&&t.data.data.user){localforage.setItem("bp_login_token",e.token),localforage.setItem("bp_user",JSON.stringify(t.data.data.user)),sessionStorage.setItem("bp_user",JSON.stringify(t.data.data.user)),m("vibebp").setToken(e.token),m("vibebp").setUser(t.data.data.user),document.querySelector("body").classList.add("vibebp-logged-in"),window.location.href=t.data.data.user.profile_link;var n=new CustomEvent("userLoaded",{detail:{userLoaded:!0}});document.dispatchEvent(n)}}))};return wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"vibebp_phoneauth_wrapper"},M?wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"vbp_message"},M):"",wp.element.createElement("div",{id:"phone-auth-recaptcha-container",className:P?"hidden":"visible"}),wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"vibebp_phoneauth_form_wrapper"},wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"vibebp_phoneauth_form loginform"},v?wp.element.createElement(p,null,wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"field"},wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"control"},wp.element.createElement("label",null,window.vibephoneauth.translations.enter_mobile_no_with_code),wp.element.createElement("input",{className:"input",type:"tel",value: _,onChange:function(e){E(e.target.value)}}))),_&&/^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$/.test(_)?wp.element.createElement("a",{className:q?"button is-primary is-loading":"button is-primary",onClick:function(){D(!0);var e=new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("phone-auth-recaptcha-container");firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(_,e).then((function(e){y(!1),j(e),k(!0),D(!1)})).catch((function(e){D(!1),V(window.vibephoneauth.translations.error_occured)}))}},window.vibephoneauth.translations.login):""):"",N?wp.element.createElement(p,null,wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"field"},wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"control"},wp.element.createElement("label",null,window.vibephoneauth.translations.enter_otp),wp.element.createElement("input",{className:"input",type:"text",value:C,onChange:function(e){I(e.target.value)}}))),C?wp.element.createElement("a",{className:U?"button is-primary -is-loading":"button is-primary",onClick:function(){$(!0),N.confirm(C).then((function(e){j(!1),k(!0);var t=e.user,n=a(a({},e.credential),{},{signInMethod:"phone_auth"});t.getIdToken().then((function(o){var i=a(a({},e),{},{user:t,credential:n,idToken:o});W(i).then((function(e){$(!1),e.status?z(e):"not_registered"==e.code&&(r(i),V(window.vibephoneauth.translations.phone_no_not_linked))}))}))})).catch((function(e){V(window.vibephoneauth.translations.code_not_confirmed)}))}},window.vibephoneauth.translations.connfirm_code):""):"",n?wp.element.createElement(p,null,wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"field"},wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"control"},wp.element.createElement("label",null,window.vibephoneauth.translations.enter_email),wp.element.createElement("input",{className:"input",type:"email",value:c,onChange:function(e){d(e.target.value)}}))),wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"field"},wp.element.createElement("div",{className:"control"},wp.element.createElement("label",null,window.vibephoneauth.translations.enter_password),wp.element.createElement("input",{className:"input",type:"password",value:b,onChange:function(e){h(e.target.value)}}))),b&&c&&function(e){return!!/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(e)}(c)?wp.element.createElement("a",{className:R?"button is-primary is-loading":"button is-primary",onClick:function(){var e,t;e=a({},n),t=a(a({},e),{},{user:a(a({},e.user),{},{email:c,password:b})}),H(!0),W(t).then((function(e){H(!1),e.status?(r(!1),document.querySelector("body").classList.add("loading"),z(e)):e.hasOwnProperty("message")&&V(e.message)})).catch((function(e){V(window.vibephoneauth.translations.error_occured)}))}},window.vibephoneauth.translations.register):""):"")))},f=wp.element,b=(f.createElement,f.render);f.useState,f.useEffect,f.Fragment,f.useContext;window.vibephoneauth.settings.enable&&document.addEventListener("login_with_mobile",(function(e){var t=document.querySelector("#login_with_mobile");if(!t){var n=document.createElement("div");n.innerHTML='<div id="login_with_phone_auth" ></div>',document.querySelector(".login_popup_content").appendChild(n)}(t=document.querySelector("#login_with_phone_auth"))&&b(wp.element.createElement(d,null),t)}))}]);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `value: "+886"`?

Comment: @samuei because the script have a onChange function using the value field :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could see, the `_` receives the phone number. Try something like this.

```js
wp.element.createElement("label", null, window.vibephoneauth.translations.enter_mobile_no_with_code), wp.element.createElement("input", {
            className: "input",
            type: "tel",
            value: '+886' + _, // Append the desired number
            onChange: function(e) {
                E(e.target.value)
            }
        })
```

Comment: I think its so close to solve this issue! Its make ```+886``` as the default value correctly but when I try to fill the text field, its keep repeat +886 every single time I typed. any idea? :)